# Conditionally selecting duplicates and selectively choosing which duplicate to keep

Tags: r

I am currently working with a large data frame for a study involving 486 observations with 7 variables in R studio (see attached image for a sample of dummy data). Two of the variables are ID numbers: the first ID number is unique for each individual person. However, sometimes a person appears more than once on the list, so there are duplicates of this first ID number. The second ID number is also unique for each person, but it lists a study visit number as a suffix (to signify that they came in over a period of time). Thus, this second ID number does not have duplicates. For example, say there was someone with a first ID number of 0001, and they have two second ID numbers of xx0001_1 (for their first visit to the lab) and xx0001_2 (for their second visit to the lab). However, the vast majority of people in the data frame only came in for one visit, so they do not have a duplicate first ID number (or second ID number, in that case).

My problem is this: I want to select only those that have duplicate first ID numbers and then filter out each of their data points such that I only keep their second visit. For example, I need to only select those with duplicate first ID numbers such as "0001", and among those I want to filter out the "xx0001_1" visit and only keep the "xx0001_2" visit.

I know that I can use the "distinct" function for the first ID number, but the problem is that this eliminates the second of the second ID numbers (e.g. xx0001_2) and keeps the first one (e.g. xx0001_1). I want to do the opposite: I want to eliminate duplicates of the first ID number, but only keep the rows that have the second visit in their second ID number (e.g. keep xx0001_2 but remove xx0001_1). I'm very new to R/coding. How can I do this? Thank you!

[Example data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxfz3.png)

```
distinct(.data, ID 1, .keep_all = T)
```

However, this code only preserves the first row. I want to eliminate the first row and instead only preserve the second row. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Does this help?

Comment: Pictures of data aren't very helpful because we don't want to retype all the data just to test. And it would be better if you showed exactly what the output should look like so possible solutions can be properly tested.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I ended up asking someone here what I should do, and they suggested that I rearrange the data so that it works with the function instead of trying to force the function to work with the data.

Comment: (See above under "SOLVED")

Comment: Add your solution as an answer below. We discourage people from editing the question to include a solution. That’s not how Stack Overflow works best. You can either move it or we can just roll the edit back.